# Packer: what's the difference between tags and snapshot_tags builder options?

Tags: packer, amazon-ebs, packer-builder

From the documentation, they doing the same (https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon-ebs.html#snapshot_tags)

Am I missing something?
In which case should I use `snapshot_tags` instead of `tags`?

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation:

`tags` - Tags applied to the AMI and relevant snapshots.

`snapshot_tags` - Tags to apply to snapshot. They will override AMI tags if already applied to snapshot.

Normally, you just need to set `tags`.